# Publishing without clickonce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

personally i hate clickonce, i like to have an own installer and updater
but that manifest file, how do i use that (or the content) when i don't publish it with clickonce
because when i just copy the .exe it runs fine and such, but i dont have a manifest file
now, i need to create a program that needs admin rights, how do i do that (include manifest or programatically) without clickonce, cuuuuz i am stuck on this

Comment: For future reference, that little 'dot' you've placed before "exe" can also be used elsewhere... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Wix, or one of the built-in installer project types.

Comment: how will that allow me to get the Manifest in it?

Comment: What manifest are you refering to?  The manifest clickonce creates is only required to do click once.  Its not required for a standard installer.

Comment: uhm, in the manifest you can set if you want to let it always run as admin, that is what i am looking for